# Об употреблении "бо" вместо "потому что"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Разумно ли использовать слово "бо" вместо словосочетания "потому что"?

Дополнение (от 12.07.2014)

Союз "бо" в пять раз короче словосочетания "потому что".

Comment: Союз "бо" употребляют чаще всего на Украине. На просторах России я ни разу этого не слышала, а вот в разговоре с украинцами - постоянно!!

Answer (score 2):

Я активно использую сабж в сетевой практике, бо так короче, круче и басче)

> Д. И. Фонвизин. Недоросль (1782)
> На что и милостивая резолюция вскоре воспоследовала, с отметкою: "Такого-то-де семинариста от всякого учения уволить: ***писано бо есть***, не мечите бисера пред свиниями, да не попрут его ногами".

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое "басче".

Comment: >Вс. В. Иванов. Рогулька (1919)  
У нас молодяжник как заиграет на гармошках, даже в ушах пищит. ***У нас басче.*** А ты на гармошке не умешь?

Басче, баской, баса...  
>**БАСА** 
 ж. сев. бас м. яросл. краса, красота, хорошество, пригожество, нарядность, изящество; украшение, наряд, украса, прикраса. То и баса, что руса коса. Сколько прибасов ни надевай, а басы не прибудет. (Даль)

Comment: Большое спасибо за разъяснение.

Answer (score 1):

Признаться честно, впервые слышу о таком слове. Вот что удалось мне найти.  Бо
союз ибо, потому что; употребит. ***в церк.***, Малороссии, Белоруссии и в соседстве. Не дам, бо нет. | Понукательное же, ну, да, кур. вор. Иди бо, садись бо, скорей бо.

Comment: Спасибо за предоставленные сведения.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте лучше использовать БО в качестве усилительной частицы, которой она изначально является. Будем говорить: давай бо, скорей бо, иди бо, садись бо.

О частице БО, которая встречается в "Слове о полку Игореве", можно почитать http://www.dm-dobrov.ru/slovo/syntax/bo-link.html Здесь говорится о том, что БО по значению была близка к ЖЕ, но при этом имела важные грамматические функции.

А вот крик чьей-то души с форума:

" Черт! Долго терпел, но более не могу. НЕТ СЛОВА "БО" В РУССКОМ ЯЗЫКЕ! НЕТ И ВСЕ ТУТ!Есть устаревшее русское "ибо", союз, означающий "потому что", "так как" и т.д.Я не стал бы посвящать этому целый пост, но именно на этих форумах в последнее время пошла какая-то мания использования этого покалеченного, омерзительного "бо". Это безграмотно! Забудьте, ибо Вас это не украшает"!

Забавно, не правда ли?

Comment: "Воскрешение" древнерусского союза *бо* раздражает ярых нормоустроителей. Но это не имеет никакого значения. Слова живут в языке вопреки запретам.  
> М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Святочный рассказ (1858)  
Жена скоро покойницей стала, бо для нас время гладно настало, а дочек-красоток люди приютили, бо родители им продовольствие прекратили, а затем остаюсь, без дальнейших слов, покорный ваш слуга Егор Павлов Абессаломов.

Comment: Думается, что во всём должна быть мера, в том числе в уместности употребления устаревших слов. Внесение их в текст должно нести какую-то художественную нагрузку, а не быть простой модой на такие слова. У нас же народ увлекающийся, и этой самой меры не знает ни в чем.

Answer (score 0):

“Бо” в смысле "ибо", "потому что" взято из украинского языка.

> Червону руту не шукай вечорами,
>   Ти у мене єдина, тільки ти, повір,
>   **Бо** твоя врода то є чистая вода,
>   То є бистрая вода з синіх гір.

([Червона рута](https://www.cheremhi.com.ua/text/slova.php?id=73))

Украинизмы иногда употребляют в русском языке в качестве сленга. Разумно ли это? Вопрос поставлен некорректно. Грамотно ли? Нет, но на сленг понятие грамотности не распространяется.